# Razor view not posting updated model data to controller - data binding fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a problem where my razor view is not providing an updated model object to the controller when the form is posted to the controller for update.

The view is designed to allow the user to make changes to existing records and save them back to the database.  Multiple updatable records are displayed on the form using '@foreach'.

The controller is providing the correct data to the view (GET), but no matter what I try, every time I POST back, or "save" the data, the object returned to the controller is the original object.  None of the changes the user makes in the view are reflected in the object when it returns to the controller to save the update.

P.S.  Don't be confused by the term "controller" in my View - this is the entity name that is getting updated, NOT the an MVC controller.

Here is the controller code:

```
    public partial class DeviceStationController : Controller
{
    // GET:
    public ActionResult MyDevicesSetup()
    {

        var tblUserDevice = db.TblUserDevices.Include(x => x.TblDevice).Include(x => x.TblDevicePrograms).Include(x => x.TblDeviceSensors).Include(x => x.TblDeviceStations).Include(x => x.TblUser).Where(x => x.TblUser.AspNetUser.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
        var UserDevice_IDs = tblUserDevice.Select(p => p.Device_ID).Distinct();
        var tblDevice = db.TblDevices.Include(x => x.TblUserDevices).Where(x => UserDevice_IDs.Contains(x.Device_ID));

        return View(tblDevice.ToList());

    }
    // POST:
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult MyDevicesSetup([Bind(Include = "Device_ID,DeviceCode,DeviceName,TimeZone,ExtBoards,Sequential,StationDelay,MasterStation,MastOnOffset,MastOffOffset,LocationZip,LocationCity,LocationCountry,DownloadFlag,LastDownload,LastUpload,RecordCreated,RecordEdited,RecordDeleted")] TblDevice tblDevice)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            tblDevice.RecordEdited = DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry(tblDevice).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("MyDevicesSetup");
        }

        return View(tblDevice);
    }
}
```

Here is the View code:

```
@model IEnumerable<AquaTame.Models.TblDevice>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Controller Setup";
}

@foreach (var controller in Model)
{
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right">
    <h4>
        @controller.DeviceName
    </h4>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyDevicesSetup", "DeviceStation", routeValues: controller))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => controller.Device_ID)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => controller.DeviceCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => controller.DeviceCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => controller.DeviceCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

@*More fields here.....  removed for brevity...*@

            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
}
@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

The HTML form tag rendered to the browser is here:

```
<form action="/DeviceStation/MyDevicesSetup?TblUserDevices=System.Collections.Generic.HashSet%601%5BAquaTame.Models.TblUserDevice%5D&amp;Device_ID=1&amp;DeviceCode=MX24B&amp;DeviceName=%231-w&amp;TimeZone=-8&amp;ExtBoards=0&amp;Sequential=True&amp;StationDelay=5&amp;MasterStation=False&amp;MastOnOffset=0&amp;MastOffOffset=0&amp;LocationZip=97124&amp;DownloadFlag=False&amp;RecordCreated=05%2F04%2F2014%2000%3A00%3A00&amp;RecordEdited=07%2F14%2F2014%2015%3A58%3A15&amp;RecordDeleted=True" method="post">

//lots of stuff here ....

</form>
```

The URL that get's POSTed is as expected; containing the original elements from GET:

```
http://localhost:59259/DeviceStation/MyDevicesSetup?TblUserDevices=System.Collections.Generic.HashSet%601%5BAquaTame.Models.TblUserDevice%5D&Device_ID=1&DeviceCode=MX24B&DeviceName=%231-w&TimeZone=-8&ExtBoards=0&Sequential=True&StationDelay=5&MasterStation=False&MastOnOffset=0&MastOffOffset=0&LocationZip=97124&DownloadFlag=False&RecordCreated=05%2F04%2F2014%2000%3A00%3A00&RecordEdited=07%2F14%2F2014%2016%3A10%3A36&RecordDeleted=True
```

Here is more of the rendered HTML from the form.  The property names seem to be retained properly, but this goes beyond my capability to understand what is happening "under the hood".  I appreciate all the helpful comments and suggestions:

```
<form action="/DeviceStation/MyDevicesSetup?TblUserDevices=System.Collections.Generic.HashSet%601%5BAquaTame.Models.TblUserDevice%5D&amp;Device_ID=1&amp;DeviceCode=MX24B&amp;DeviceName=%231-w&amp;TimeZone=-8&amp;ExtBoards=0&amp;Sequential=True&amp;StationDelay=5&amp;MasterStation=False&amp;MastOnOffset=0&amp;MastOffOffset=0&amp;LocationZip=97124&amp;DownloadFlag=False&amp;RecordCreated=05%2F04%2F2014%2000%3A00%3A00&amp;RecordEdited=07%2F14%2F2014%2016%3A11%3A21&amp;RecordDeleted=True" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="7-wHfkHpP50iZ4pekCWhIe0ahkvvE7KapaJjFkEhBfjZwtu8-bBfJvG1Pg-9ILn0FsXnrj8Jq1TJQKrq5DxQkaLxd7AVcxsQjqJegrwJL4VDIeR5H68QEPmqOQOu9AIIfdYzqON-iUDv4dFGg5IkXg2">
<div class="form-horizontal">
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Device_ID must be a number." data-val-required="The Device_ID field is required." id="controller_Device_ID" name="controller.Device_ID" type="hidden" value="1">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="controller_DeviceCode">DeviceCode</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="controller_DeviceCode" name="controller.DeviceCode" type="text" value="MX24B"></div>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="controller.DeviceCode" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2" for="controller_DeviceName">DeviceName</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="ui-input-text ui-body-inherit ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset">
            <input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-length="The field DeviceName must be a string with a maximum length of 8." data-val-length-max="8" id="controller_DeviceName" name="controller.DeviceName" type="text" value="#1-w"></div>
            <span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="controller.DeviceName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    @*More form fields in here, removed for brevity........*@
    <div class="ui-btn ui-input-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">Save<input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default"></div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am making some progress with everyone's help.  I am brand new to MS MVC Entity Framework and self-taught, so I am afraid I lack some critical knowledge.  I have removed the "controller" object parameter from the HTML BeginForm helper and made sure that the form has all the fields available.  I have added the Binding Prefix "controller" to the binding on the controller (very confusing, I know).  I am now getting null data returned to the controller, so I must still be doing something wrong.

Here is the Controller code:

```
        [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    //public ActionResult MyDevicesSetup([Bind(Prefix = "controller")] TblDevice tblDevice)
    public ActionResult MyDevicesSetup([Bind(Prefix = "controller", Include = "Device_ID,DeviceCode,DeviceName,TimeZone,ExtBoards,Sequential,StationDelay,MasterStation,MastOnOffset,MastOffOffset,LocationZip,LocationCity,LocationCountry,DownloadFlag,LastDownload,LastUpload,RecordCreated,RecordEdited,RecordDeleted")] TblDevice tblDevice)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            tblDevice.RecordEdited = DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry(tblDevice).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            //return RedirectToAction("MyDevicesSetup");
        }
        return View(tblDevice);
    }
}
```

And here is the Razor View code:

```
@model IEnumerable<AquaTame.Models.TblDevice>

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Controller Setup";
}

@foreach (var controller in Model)
{
<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right">
    <h4>
        @controller.DeviceName
    </h4>
    @*@using (Html.BeginForm("MyDevicesSetup", "DeviceStation", routeValues: controller))*@

        @using (Html.BeginForm("MyDevicesSetup", "DeviceStation"))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="form-horizontal">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => controller.Device_ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => controller.DownloadFlag)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => controller.LastDownload)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => controller.LastUpload)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => controller.RecordCreated)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => controller.RecordEdited)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => controller.RecordDeleted)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => controller.DeviceCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => controller.DeviceCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => controller.DeviceCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

@*Remaining form fields follow - left out for brevity...*@

                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    }
```

And finally, here is the from POST data sent to the controller:

```
__RequestVerificationToken:NO1PIEHxKyzlNldFuOOt-

EZhiU5VDe1Ax8CI9xzEzvViSgBqECKzmLrDRIdJeNOzMMJDaA-GTTBt5OeueTvnCKK6hK7MK_51EtANrVjwb5m4zVQY6tlHbnJcw3mdO9m5YhZi2eskyq4NhoHJHooL0g2
controller.Device_ID:1
controller.DownloadFlag:False
controller.LastDownload:
controller.LastUpload:
controller.RecordCreated:5/4/2014 12:00:00 AM
controller.RecordEdited:7/14/2014 4:11:21 PM
controller.RecordDeleted:True
controller.DeviceCode:MX24c
controller.DeviceName:#1-w
controller.TimeZone:-8
controller.ExtBoards:0
controller.Sequential:true
controller.Sequential:false
controller.StationDelay:5
controller.MasterStation:false
controller.MastOnOffset:0
controller.MastOffOffset:0
controller.LocationZip:97124
controller.LocationCity:
controller.LocationCountry:
```

Comment: When you pick one of your forms and submit it, what is the actual HTML markup of that form?  What are the values captured in the POST request?  (You can inspect these with browser debugging tools, such as Firebug or Chrome tools.)

Comment: replace for each with for loop

Comment: On the POST, is the data being updated in the database?

Comment: What's the purpose of `routeValues: controller`? I'm suspecting the model binder is using this to bind to.

Comment: @Dbloch - the data IS getting updated in the database, but it is the OLD values, not the edits made by the user..  The model object the controller is getting on post, doesn't contain the edits made by the user in the view.

Comment: @Shoe - the 'routeValues: controller' is the model object passed back to the controller - the row to be updated.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - Replacing 'foreach' with 'for' didn't help.

Comment: You need to remove `routeValues:controller` You want the new data to be in the form data, not in the route data.

Comment: @David - The HTML rendered is as expected - see my update to posting.

Comment: @shoe - If I remove the 'routevalues: controller' parameter, then the model object returned to the controller contains all null, false, and 0 values and the 'SaveChanges' fails for 'EntityValidationErrors'.

Comment: I don't understand `routevalues: controller`. What is the value of controller, is it the controller in charge of the get/postback?  If so it should NOT be in routevalues, [it should just be a string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492590(v=vs.118).aspx).

Comment: @ChrisS, I'd like to repeat the question asked above by David. Could you please post the body of your POST request as it is coming through.

Comment: It contains all `null` because your binder is resolving to a`IEnumerable<TblDevice>` not a single `TblDevice`. This is evidenced by the generated html. `controller.Device_ID`... if `TblDevice` doesn't have an object named `Controller` with a property `Device_ID` then the binding fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I finally discovered the solution (2 parts) to the problem with the help of @zespri and @Shoe.  The first part was to get rid of `routeValues: controller` in the view and add `[Bind(Prefix = "controller")]` to my POST action method parameter.  When I continued to get null data returned, I discovered the second critical problem.  The variable named `"controller"` must be causing some kind of conflict (is it a reserved word in C#?) because as soon as I changed it to "cntrlr", everything worked.  I double checked and reproduced the problem, so I am pretty sure that using the word `"controller"` as the variable name was causing a problem.  Thanks for the help everyone!

The working controller code is here:

```
   public partial class DeviceStationController : Controller
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult MyDevicesSetup([Bind(Prefix = "ctrlr", Include = "Device_ID,DeviceCode,DeviceName,TimeZone,ExtBoards,Sequential,StationDelay,MasterStation,MastOnOffset,MastOffOffset,LocationZip,LocationCity,LocationCountry,DownloadFlag,LastDownload,LastUpload,RecordCreated,RecordEdited,RecordDeleted")] TblDevice tblDevice)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                tblDevice.RecordEdited = DateTime.Now;
                db.Entry(tblDevice).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("MyDevicesSetup");
            }
            return View(tblDevice);
        }
    }
```

And the Razor View code is here:

```
@model IEnumerable<AquaTame.Models.TblDevice>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Controller Setup";
}

@foreach (var ctrlr in Model)
{
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right">
        <h4>
            @ctrlr.DeviceName
        </h4>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("MyDevicesSetup", "DeviceStation"))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.Device_ID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.DownloadFlag)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.LastDownload)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.LastUpload)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.RecordCreated)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.RecordEdited)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => ctrlr.RecordDeleted)
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceCode, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceCode, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceCode, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => ctrlr.DeviceName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

@* More form fields in here....*@

                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        }
    </div>
}
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of `routeValues: controller` in your view and add `[Bind(Prefix = "controller")]` to your action method parameter instead.

Your `routeValues: controller` is masking your problem, not solving it. It adds this long query string to your form action and then to the posted URL. The data from the posted form come from the POST request not from the url, although the default model binder can process both. So what's happening in your case is that it takes these unchanged data that you fudged in but it can't bind the postback data because they are associated with the "`controller`" variable from your view, and the action method parameter has a different name: `tblDevice`. You need to add the prefix parameter to the Bind attribute to resolve this.

In addition, in situations like this I strongly recommend looking in the postback data, as they immediately provide a clue as to what might go wrong (in this case the prefix). David suggested this to you in the very first comment, but you perhaps overlooked this suggestion.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.  I am brand new and self-taught at MS MVC Entity Framework, so please forgive my lack of certain knowledge.  I understand now about the the Binding Prefix and about viewing the POST data using built-in Chrome debugger.  That is very useful indeed.  I am still stuck with getting nulls returned to the controller.  I have tried multiple ways of using the Prefix, and making sure all the fields are available from the form.  I am still missing something obvious, I am afraid.

Comment: So when you break into debugger inside MyDevicesSetup, what is null, tblDevice or its properties?

Comment: The tblDevice itself is null when you break into the controller routine.  There are no properties.